# make boost python pick up the correct python version on osx

Tags: c++, python, boost, shared-libraries

Im currently building a module with boost python and I cant get it to build against the correct version of python(I need it to build against 2.6). The first thing I tried was setting my PATH to that of the version of python I'd like to install, but that built a module that would only run on the default system version, 2.7. Next I tried adding `--with-python-version=2.6` as an argument for bootstrap but that didnt work either.

I'm new to c++ and I'm building someone else's code so apologies if there is a blindingly obvious answer

Comment: Do you mean when you run cmake/make/<build> , or related to the actual c++ code?

Comment: i build boost with bjam and the final program is built with cmake

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what solves your issue, but it sounds like something I had dealt with when building another boost project. It would constantly find the wrong python installation no matter what I do. Namely, it always wanted the system python. I addressed it by telling it to look at another INCLUDE location:

```
cmake -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
```